# How do detect missing @Nested annotations?

Tags: junit5

When using nested tests, my team has found that sometimes we forget to add an `@Nested` annotation to an inner class.

This leads to a "false negative" test suite -- all tests are green but in reality there's a subset of the tests that are not running at all, and may indeed be broken.

Are there any existing tools that can help us spot this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is currently no tool that will help you in that regard.

As far as JUnit Jupiter itself is concerned, we (the JUnit 5 team) are planning to overhaul *diagnostics* for such scenarios in a future release.

Feel free to chime in with your thoughts and concerns here:

https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/242

Comment: Thanks! Since there's no solution for now, I'm marking your answer as the accepted, and I've [submitted a feature request for it](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1736).

Comment: You're welcome, and... thanks for submitting the feature request.